# What type of View is used?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been trying to figured out what kind of View was the 2 rectangle, I would like to use the same kind of design. I though at first it was a CardView but I think it can be since they are not the same.

Sorry if my question is really basic, I'm still on the learning process.

[image]

Comment: Which portion of the screen are you referring to here? None of these views require a complex or specialized View subclass, but there may be some that can give you some additional stuff for free.

Comment: I'm talking about the 2 white rectangle, the one where you can see her profile with name, phone num,ect. And the second one that said "A propos de moi".

I want to have the same design but I don't think they areregular TextView and they are not CardView neither I believe, I would like to know what is this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This view is not one single view, but rather a compound view. To reproduce this type of view, I would recommend, broadly, something like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <CardView>
        <TextView/> //Name
        <TextView/> //Location w/ drawableStart set
        <TextView/> //Phone w/ drawableStart set
        <TextView/> //link w/ drawableStart set
    </CardView>
    <CardView>
        <TextView/> //Title
        <TextView/> //Body
    </CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are CardView only, give a light gray background for the root layout and for card views give elevation and corner radius.